# Add _Click funciton to generated button WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-core-3.1, tablelayoutpanel

I have a question about adding a function to a generated button. I want to be able to go to another .cs by pressing a button.

The exact event:

```
PartnerInfo partnerInfo = new PartnerInfo();
partnerInfo.Show();
```

The button is being generated in a 'TableLayoutPanel' at each row. The code I am using now for the table:

```
//get a reference to the previous existent 
RowStyle temp = MyPartnersPanel.RowStyles[MyPartnersPanel.RowCount - 1];
//increase panel rows count by one
MyPartnersPanel.RowCount++;

//add a new RowStyle as a copy of the previous one
MyPartnersPanel.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(temp.SizeType, temp.Height));
//add your controls
MyPartnersPanel.Controls.Add(
  new TextBox() {
    Text = PartnerName, ReadOnly=true }, 0, MyPartnersPanel.RowCount - 1);
    MyPartnersPanel.Controls.Add(new TextBox() { Text = PartnerLevel, ReadOnly = true }, 1, MyPartnersPanel.RowCount - 1);
    MyPartnersPanel.Controls.Add(new TextBox() { Text = PartnerGoal, ReadOnly = true }, 2, MyPartnersPanel.RowCount - 1);
    MyPartnersPanel.Controls.Add(new TextBox() { Text = WorkoutPerWeek, ReadOnly = true }, 3, MyPartnersPanel.RowCount - 1);
    MyPartnersPanel.Controls.Add(new Button() { Text = "+", BackColor = Color.Black, ForeColor = Color.White, Height = 29, }, 4, MyPartnersPanel.RowCount - 1);
)};
```

Any help is very appreciated.
And I am working in .NET Core 3.1 if that matters

Comment: You mean to assign a method to the button's click event? `btn.Click += ClickEventMethod`

Comment: You need two steps : Button newButton = new Button() { Text = "+", BackColor = Color.Black, ForeColor = Color.White, Height = 29, }, 4, MyPartnersPanel.RowCount - 1) MyPartnersPanel.Controls.Add(newButton); newButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);

Comment: Added your code and created the event button1_Click, i get error on the 
"4, MyPartnersPanel.RowCount - 1" I noticed you do not close the 1. so try with and without and it just seems to give two different errors..
Without it is expecting ";" three times?
With ";" there is only 2 ";" + identifier + "}"expected
https://imgur.com/a/DIHg8AY @jdweng

Comment: You need a click method like private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }  Here is the corrected code :             Button newButton = new Button() { Text = "+", BackColor = Color.Black, ForeColor = Color.White, Height = 29};
            MyPartnersPanel.Controls.Add(newButton, 4, MyPartnersPanel.RowCount - 1);

Comment: Ah yes, it is working now! Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the statement where you create the button into two, so you can access the button:

```
MyPartnersPanel.Controls.Add(new Button() { Text = ...
```

Should be:

```
Button btn  new Button() {Text = ...};
MyPartnersPanel.Controls.Add(btn);

// attach an event handler:
btn.Clicked += this.ButtonClickedEventHandler;

private void ButtonClickedEventHandler(object sender, ...)
{
    ...
}
```